# Splitting PHP generators

Tags: php, iterator, generator

I've just written part of a generator, and reached the point where it functions correctly, but needs some refactoring. The structure of the method is as follows:

```
public function getFlattenedList( array $elements ) {
    foreach ( $elements as $element ) {
        if ( $this->someCondition( $element ) ) {
            // A pile of stuff here

            if ( $anotherCondition ) {
                for ( $i = 0; $i < $this->someValue(); $i++ ) {
                    yield $this->anotherOperation( $element );
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            yield $this->someOperation( $element );
        }
    }
}
```

This method is to big/complex. The most obvious thing to do is move out the body of the if branch to its own method. Something like this

```
public function getFlattenedList( array $elements ) {
    foreach ( $elements as $element ) {
        if ( $this->someCondition( $element ) ) {
            // ???
            $this->getFlattenedElement( $element );
        }
        else {
            yield $this->someOperation( $element );
        }
    }
}

private function getFlattenedElement() {
    // A pile of stuff here

    if ( $anotherCondition ) {
        for ( $i = 0; $i < $this->someValue(); $i++ ) {
            yield $this->anotherOperation( $element );
        }
    }
}
```

But of course I cannot just return the result of this new function, since it also is a generator. (And I want it to be a generator, so the work is only done when the value is requested.) What I did to make this work is adding yet another loop, inside the body of the if condition:

```
public function getFlattenedList( array $elements ) {
    foreach ( $elements as $element ) {
        if ( $this->someCondition( $element ) ) {
            foreach ( $this->getFlattenedElement( $element ) as $flattened ) {
                yield $flattened;
            }
        }
        else {
            yield $this->someOperation( $element );
        }
    }
}
```

Is it somehow possible to avoid having to add that loop, while keeping the generator behaviour and splitting up the method nicely? I've not used generators before, so might be missing something obvious.

Comment: Why not eliminate the `foreach ( $this->getFlattenedElement( $element ) as $flattened ) {
                yield $flattened;
            }
` loop with a simple `yield $this->getFlattenedElement( $element );` Try it! Your looping is being handled by the `getFlattenedElement()` generator

Comment: I tried this, but then my test fails, so it's definitely not equivalent. If I do this, it will yield the generator and thus have a result of type `Generator` no?

Comment: Well there's no reason why it shouldn't work: it shouldn't yield the generator, but should yield the result from the generator.... recursive generators do work

Comment: If I call `iterator_to_array` on the result of the public generator, the array ends up containing Generator instances. `[ ResultClass 0, Generator, ResultClass 3 ]` instead of `[ ResultClass 0, ResultClass 1, ResultClass 2, ResultClass 3 ]`. That is not what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're actually trying to do is known as Generator delegation, and now it has become a question of PHP version. Only PHP version 7 and up support generator delegation and it looks like this:

```
function gen_y() {
    yield 1;
    yield 2;
}

function gen_x() {
    yield from gen_y();
    yield from gen_y();
}
```

This will give you exactly the desired effect or 'recursive' or 'nested' or 'delegated' generator calls. But the issue now is PHP7. Not many production environments run PHP7. For that you'd need to write another generator that takes a generator that yields generators. Like a converter.

I won't paste the code onto here but I recently ran into this problem which compelled me to write a package to do just this in PHP5: [hedronium/generator-nest](https://github.com/Hedronium/GeneratorNest)

While using this package you just yield generators, and wrap the initial generator call with a method the package provides.

```
use Hedronium\GeneratorNest\GeneratorNest;

function gen_x() {
    yield gen_y();
    yield gen_y();
}

foreach (GeneratorNest::nested(gen_x()) as $x) {
    // Your Code.
}
```

I'd encourage you to look at the source to get a feel for what's actually going on. It's [only 28 lines](https://github.com/Hedronium/GeneratorNest/blob/master/src/GeneratorNest.php).;)